# SVNLOOK changed in postcommit hook - batch file

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, hook, post-commit-hook

I am having trouble printing the list of changes. Everytime I run my script and check the value, it is blank.

```
postcommithook.bat
set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2
set TXN_NAME=%3
set LF = ^

SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0

set svnlook = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%svnlook% svnlook author -r %REV% %REPOS%') do set AUTH_NAME=%%a

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set MSG = for /f %%i in ('svnlook changed -r %REV% %REPOS%') do (
SET "VAR=!VAR!!LF%%i"
SET "PAR=!PAR!^^!LF!!LF!%%i"
)
set DIRS_CHANGED = !VAR!
endlocal

SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%emailer.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%' '%REPOS%' '%REV%' '%TXN_NAME%' '%AUTH_NAME%' '%DIRS_CHANGED%'";
```

I understand I am doing a mistake somewhere in the loop where I am calling the changes function. How would I be able to get the list of changed directories and pass it to the mailer script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `LF` is not going to contain a new-line here; you must remove the spaces around the `=`-sign, and you must have *two* empty lines following the `set LF=^` line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here: 
I have removed the loop where the command 'svn changed' is done. Instead I store the output in a separate file and then commence processing it via a powershell/vbscript file for an e-mail to be generated.

Replaced the below:

```
svnlook changed %REPOS% -r %REV% > %ThisScriptsDirectory%tmp_log.txt
```

Instead of

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set MSG = for /f %%i in ('svnlook changed -r %REV% %REPOS%') do (
SET "VAR=!VAR!!LF%%i"
SET "PAR=!PAR!^^!LF!!LF!%%i"
)
set DIRS_CHANGED = !VAR!
endlocal
```

Thanks,
Venkat.